# jQuery throws uncaught error on smarty code

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have the following error message

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value={if isset($smarty.post.id_state)}{$smarty.post.id_state|intval}{/if}]
```

Which originating from this code:

```
$('.id_state option[value={if isset($smarty.post.id_state) {$smarty.post.id_state|intval}{/if}]').prop('selected', true);
```

I am not sure why it throws such error, since the code following it (literallly the next line) works like a charm

The following code works normally

```
$('.id_state_invoice option[value={if isset($smarty.post.id_state_invoice)}{$smarty.post.id_state_invoice|intval}{/if}]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: you miss the `}` after `($smarty.post.id_state)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code:

```
{if isset($smarty.post.id_state) {$smarty.post.id_state|intval}{/if}
```

needs to be:

```
{if isset($smarty.post.id_state)}{$smarty.post.id_state|intval}{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, i think i need more caffeine now

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing } after isset().